# Unable to get invalid emails

Tags: c++

I'm unable to get invalid emails to print in my code. I'm able to call the student roster just fine but that's about it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
#include "degree.h"
#include "roster.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

const string studentData[] =
{
"A1,John,Smith,John1989@gm ail.com,20,30,35,40,SECURITY",
"A2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,50,30,40,NETWORK",
"A3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,20,40,33,SOFTWARE",
"A4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,50,58,40,SECURITY",
};

Roster* classRoster = new Roster(numberOfStudents);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i)
{
cout << studentData[i] << "," << endl;
}

cout << endl;

cout << "Invalid emails:";

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i)
{
classRoster->printInvalidEmails();
}



cout << "Average days per class for each student" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i)
{
cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

classRoster->printByDegreeProgram();
cout << endl;




system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Here is my roster.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
#include "degree.h"
#include "roster.h"

using namespace std;


Roster::Roster()
{
This->rosterSize = 0;
this->lastIndex = -1;
this->classRosterArray = nullptr;
}

Roster::Roster(int rosterSize)
{
this->rosterSize = rosterSize;
this->lastIndex = -1;
this->classRosterArray = new Student * [rosterSize];
}


void Roster::add(string studentId, string firstName, string lastName, 
string 
emailAddress, int age, 
int daysInCourse1, int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, Degree degree)
{

}




void Roster::remove(string studentId)
{

for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; ++i)
{
if (classRosterArray[i] == nullptr)
{
cout << "ERROR: Student with ID: " << studentId << " not found" << 
endl;
break;
}
else if (studentId == classRosterArray[i]->getStudentId())
{
classRosterArray[i] = nullptr;
cout << "Student removed" << endl;
}
}

}

void Roster::printAll()
{
for (int i = 0; i <= this->lastIndex; ++i)
{
(this->classRosterArray)[i]->print();
}
}

void Roster::printAverageDaysInCourse(string studentId)
{
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; ++i) {
if ((*classRosterArray[i]).getStudentId() == studentId) {
found = true;
int average = 0;
average = (classRosterArray[i]->getNumberOfDaysToCompleteCourse() 
[0] 
+ classRosterArray[i]->getNumberOfDaysToCompleteCourse()[1] + 
classRosterArray[i]->getNumberOfDaysToCompleteCourse()[2]) / 
3;
cout << "Average days it took student " << studentId << " to 
complete 
a course: " << average 
<< " days" << endl;
}
}
if (!found) cout << "Student not found." << endl;
}

void Roster::printInvalidEmails()
{
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i)
{
string email = classRosterArray[i]->getEmailAddress();
bool isBad = false;
size_t at = email.find("@");
size_t period = email.find(".");
if (at == string::npos)
{
cout << "Invalid email. Missing @ symbol." << endl;
}
else if (period == string::npos)
{
cout << "Invalid email. Missing a period." << endl;
} 
else if (email.find(" ") != string::npos)
{
cout << "Invalid email. Spaces not allowed." << endl;
}
}
}


void Roster::printByDegreeProgram()
{
for (int i = 0; i < degreeType; ++i) 
{
cout << &Roster::printByDegreeProgram;
}

    
}





Roster::~Roster()
 {
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i)
{
delete classRosterArray[i];
}
}
```

I'm just starting out and am not sure if i've totally messed myself up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I thought might have been able to figure it out and i've tried a few different times but still unable to correct.

Comment: Your `Roster` class allocates an array of `Student*` pointers, but doesn't point them at any valid `Student` objects. You should be allocating an array of `Student` objects instead. And then you need to populate those `Student` objects with data before performing other operations on them, like searching and printing.

Comment: Don't forget about C++ being able to do `for (auto& student : classRosterArray)` to reduce how much code you need to write. You'll also want to use `std::vector<Student>` if possible, or wrappers like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to automatically destroy objects that are allocated as pointers.